Ghidra refuses to retype local variable
I have a fairly large function that I'm trying to decompile in Ghidra. There's a local variable (that either I have incorrectly typed, or Ghidra did it itself) that I try to retype to int. They are the same size in memory. It has some incorrect enum type.
I right-click on it and select "Retype variable" and then type "int" and click OK:

Ghidra starts churning something and then after a second or two ... nothing changes.
Why is it refusing to change the type this local variable?

Though I am loath to direct traffic away from this site, for some tool-specific issues it may be more effective to open an issue at the Ghidra repo, especially if it may be a bug. If you do take that route, please include a link to the issue in this post. It's also possible there's a related issue there already, I haven't checked.
